# I'm having a hard time understanding the stabbing -> Clojure shorthand

Tags: clojure

In Clojure, what does (-> ... ... ...) means? Changing the order of things results a different output.

```lisp
(defn my-method
  "description"
  [& args]
  (-> things/thing1
      things/thing2
      things/thing3
      things/thing4
      things/thing5))
```

Comment: `->` and `->>` are called the threading macros (`->` is called thread-first and `->>` is thread-last), take a look at: http://blog.fogus.me/2009/09/04/understanding-the-clojure-macro/ for a great explanation about the thread-first macro and about the name.

Comment: As an aside, the reason the order changes the output is because your functions are not associative, not because of the threading. For instance. if your functions thing2 to thing5 were all "+" then order wouldn't matter (in that case you'd actually need an argument too, but the point is valid). I always read the `->` function as "on <first arg> perform <second arg>, then <third arg>, ..." effectively "threading" the result through every function in turn. It's a lot easier to read `(-> a b c d e f)` than `(f (e (d (c (b a)))))`

Answer (score 5):

This is ["thread-first"](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/-%3E) macro:

```
(-> a b c)
```

is equivalent to

```
(c (b a))
```

Basically this macro is used to avoid nesting big amount of forms. It just inserts first form as first argument of second form: `(-> a b)` becomes `(b a)`. Then resulting form is inserted as first argument of third form: `(-> (b a) c)` becomes `(c (b a))`. So, your example is equivalent to:

```
(defn my-method
  "description"
  [& args]
  (things/thing5 (things/thing4 (things/thing3 (things/thing2 things/thing1)))))
```

Answer (score 2):

`(doc)` is a convenient utility that is running in a Clojure REPL. It should be at the corner of everyday's development.

> user=> (doc ->)
>       clojure.core/->
>       ([x & forms])
>       Macro
>       Threads the expr through the forms. Inserts x as the
>     second item in the first form, making a list of it if it is not a
>     list already. If there are more forms, inserts the first form as the
>     second item in second form, etc.